# how to make vertical menu horizontal remove bullets underline and change font with css?

Tags: html, css

How do I make my vertical menu horizontal, change the font and underline, and also remove the bullets using CSS?

```
<div class="nav-menu"> </div>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="menu.html">Our menu</a></li>
<li><a href="Location.html">Our Locations</a>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>   
</ul>


.nav-menu {float:left;
          list-style-type: none;
          font-family: "heiti sc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `<ul>` is not contained within your `<nav class="nav-menu">`.  Start by putting it inside.  Then you can target the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements within:

```
.nav-menu li {
  list-style: none;   <------ this removes the bullets
  display: inline;    <------ this makes it horizontal, can also use inline-block
  font-family: "heiti sc"
}

.nav-menu li a,
.nav-menu li a:hover,
.nav-menu li a:active,
.nav-menu li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;   <--- removes underline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-menu > ul {
          list-style : none;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin : 0;
          padding : 0;
}
.nav-menu > ul > li {
          float:left;
}
.nav-menu > ul > li > a{
              text-decoration : none;
              font-family: "heiti sc";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="nav-menu"> </div>
<ul class="noballs">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="menu.html">Our menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="Location.html">Our Locations</a>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>   
</ul>


.noballs li {list-style: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's maybe some more help, have some other things added for visuals but it does what you ask.

```
.nav-menu {
    width: 850px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-color:#1b277e;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

.nav-menu li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.nav-menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: -1px;
    height: 12px;
    padding: 4px 20px 9px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #737cc9;
    border: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #1b277e;
    border-right: 1px solid #1b277e;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hickmanjos/zp4qz08L/)